# Eliminate Repeated Strings in Oracle

Tags: sql, string, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hello guys this is my first question in here :)

- I have a record in table: "250MB RAW DATA 250MB RAW DATA"
- I want to change record to this: "250MB RAW DATA"

How can i eliminate second "250MB RAW DATA" string?

But all of my records not like this. In this case I have to change only repeated records

Thank you for answer

Comment: Interesting one - I haven't got time to try out but I guess regex_replace is our friend here unless duplicates are always like the above ie column contains only the duplicated text and nothing else. If so, may be easier with case when based on substring before half the value and after - if they are equal then just the first substring else the whole value

Comment: Half the value length I should have said there

Comment: And of course if there is a space between duplicated text account for that

Comment: Great idea! Thank you for very helpful answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression to see if the value is duplicated:

```
select val, 
       (case when val = substr(val, 1, length(val) / 2) || ' ' || substr(val, 1, length(val) / 2)
             then substr(val, 1, length(val) / 2)
             else val
        end) as half_val
from (select '250MB RAW DATA 250MB RAW DATA' as val from dual union all
      select '250MB RAW DATA' from dual
     ) x;
```

Comment: It will only remove the duplicate data if they are adjacent and also it will not remove the duplicate data if there is more than two duplicates in the string-- `250MB RAW DATA 250MB RAW DATA 250MB RAW DATA` will not be corrected.

Comment: There is no more than two duplicates in the string in this case. So Gordon's approach is helpful for me. Thank you :)